# How do you graphically understand this definition of Taylor's theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion

Today, we learned about Taylor's theorem, and how a real valued function $f: (a,b) \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, and with some further criterions, can be approximated with a polynomial.

I've seen the Taylor approximation before, often in this form:

$f(x) =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!}(x-x_0)^n$

Personally, I think this definition is quite intuitive. I've seen many youtube videos that describe how this formula arises. However, our lecturer showed us another definition instead, that we'll be using. Instead of memorizing it, I want to try and understand every single part of it.

From here on, I'll present the definition, and pinpoint every part of it that I struggle to understand. So here it is:

> $f: (a,b) \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, where $f$ is $(n+1)$ times continously differentiable on $(a,b)$. Let $x_0 \in(a,b), \forall y \in \mathbb{R} : x_0 + y \in (a,b), \exists \theta = \theta (x) \in (0,1) : f(x_0 + y) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!}y^k + \frac{f^{(n+1)}(x_0+\theta y)}{n+1!}y^{n+1}$

Wow, that took a while :) First and foremost, I want to establish that I do understand that the first term is equal to our Taylor polynomial, whereas the last term is Lagrange's residue term.

So here are all my thoughts on this definition:

- What role does $\theta$ play in this definition? How can we graphically interpret how this $\theta$ in some way or another, has an effect on the error term? I hope I expressed myself clearly enough regarding this question.
- Why do we have an $f(x_0 +y)$ and not an $f(x)$ as presented in the first definition above.

At the moment, that's all the questions I want to ask you. If you have any more ideas that you could share, that could help me further understand this definition, I'd be glad if you could share them. Whatever they might be.

Thanks!

Comment: Starting from the second question, the $x_0+y$ and $x$ are the same. The $\theta$ is just saying that the residual is evaluated somewhere between $x$ and $x_0$

Answer (score 1):

Taylor's theorem is a special case of Hermite polynomial interpolation. In Taylor's theorem, you have $x_0 \in (a, b)$ and you want a polynomial $p$ such that $p^{(k)}(x_0) = f^{(k)}(x_0)$ for all $k \in \{0, 1, \dots, n\}$. By writing $p(x) = a_0 + a_1(x - x_0) + \dots + a_n(x - x_0)^n$ and differentiating, it is easy to see that $p(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n}\frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!}(x - x_0)^k$ is the unique polynomial of degree at most $n$ that solves the problem.

It remains to estimate the error. There are many proofs giving rise to various error formulas. To get the one you wrote we can argue via Rolle's theorem. Suppose we want to find the error $f(y) - p(y)$ at $y \in (a, b)$. If $y = x_0$, the problem is trivial, so assume $y \neq x_0$; actually assume $y > x_0$, the proof for the case $y < x_0$ will be similar. Let $K = \frac{f(y) - p(y)}{(y - x_0)^{n + 1}}$ so that
$$f(y) = p(y) + K(y - x_0)^{n + 1}.$$
You can think of this as extending $p$ to interpolate $y$. Consider $F : (a, b) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$F(x) = f(x) - p(x) - K(x - x_0)^{n + 1}.$$
Note that $F$ has the two zeroes $x_0, y$. By Rolle's theorem, $F'$ has a zero $y_1 \in (x_0, y)$. Note that $F'$ has the two zeroes $x_0, y_1$. Thus by Rolle's theorem, $F''$ has a zero $y_2 \in (x_0, y_1)$. Continuing in this way (by induction), we find that $F^{(n)}$ has a zero $y_n \in (x_0, y_{n - 1})$, and finally that $F^{(n + 1)}$ has a zero $y_{n + 1} \in (x_0, y_n)$. Plugging this in gives
$$0 = f^{(n + 1)}(y_{n + 1}) - 0 - (n + 1)!K,$$
so that
$$K = \frac{f^{(n + 1)}(y_{n + 1})}{(n + 1)!}.$$

Graphically, we can say that $y_{n + 1} \in (x_0, y)$ is a zero of $F^{(n + 1)}$.